# Writing " to a file in bash

Tags: bash

Simply I need to write

```
"echo" t${count} = "$"t${count}"
```

To a text file, including all the So the output would be something like:

```
echo "  t1  = $t1"
```

With " as they are. So I have tried:

```
count=1
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(<TEST.txt))
IFS="$saveIFS"
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
echo "echo" t${count} = "$"t${count}""
(( count++ ))
done >> long1.txt
```

And variations on this such as:

```
echo "echo" """"" t${count} = "$"t${count}""
```

But I guess the wrapping in double " is only for variables.

Ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's actually no wrapping in double quotes for variables, first quote starts, the second quote ends the quoted string. You may however concatenate strings however you want, so `"$"t${count}""` will actually be equivalent to `"$"t${count}`, beginning with a quoted $-sign, followed by 't', followed by the count-variable.

Back to your question, to get a ", you can either put it in a literal string (surrounded by single quotes), like so `echo '"my string"'`, note though that variables are not substituted in literal strings. Or you can escape it, like so `echo "\"my string\""`, which will put a literal " in the string, and won't terminate it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the doublequote (also dollar sign):

```
echo "\" t = \$t\""
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "echo \"t${count} = $t${count}\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another quoting variant (more of an exercise than a solution of course):

```
# concatenate alternating single- & double-quoted blocks of substrings
count=1
echo 'echo "t'"${count}"' = $t'"${count}"'"'
```